# Error in .../component1.ng.html:21:93 caused by: this._hammer.Pan is not a constructor at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor]

Tags: angular-material2

I'm trying to use mdTooltip but when I do, I get this error:

Error in .../component1.ng.html:21:93 caused by: this._hammer.Pan is not a constructor at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor]

I added hammer js to my project but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we were using the wrong version of hammerjs for the version of angular/material that we were using.